# Values changing when app turns from portrait mode to landscape mode in android

Tags: android

I am working on android apps. My app should work both in portrait and landscape mode. I adjusted all the layouts by keeping all layout files in layout-lan folder. But now my issue is with functionality i.e when the app is changed to landscape mode the values of my parameters are changing and due to this I am getting crashes. i.e i kept a counter value but it is displaying wrong count value when turned to port-lan. Also the functionality is changing due to this. 
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: you need to post some code and your logcat so we can see the issues you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you rotate the devide, onCreate method is being called again. You can save the values by overriding onSavedInstanceState and get them back in onRestoreInstanceState or in onCreate method. For example:

save the value:

```
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean("booleanValue", true);
}
```

restore the value (you can call this in onCreate as well):

```
 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("booleanValue")) {
            boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("booleanValue");
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity restarts every time the orientation changes.

You have to store your values in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore them in `onRestoreInstanceState`. You will find the details here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

those values change because the activity gets destroyed and re-built during rotation,

please check the developers guide on how to save your activity state.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState